# Keep getting index out the range and the tables don't get displayed correctly, probably due to DispatchQueue

Tags: swift, tableview, swift5

I have it set up, so that every time the date picker changes a new data is displayed in a tableview. I need to change dates couple of times so that I have tables display something, and then it start updating correctly but after while I keep getting "index out of range error".I suspect that Im not using DispatchQueue properly. 
Whats wrong with my code?

Thank

```
var showNumberOfRes: Int = 0

class HomeViewController:  UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var restaurants = [Results]()     

    func todaysDate() -> String {

        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let result = formatter.string(from: date)

        return result
    }

    @IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        selectedDate = sender.date

    }

    var selectedDate : Date = Date() {
           didSet {
               let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
               dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES_POSIX")
               dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

             returnJson()

           }
       }

    func returnJson(){

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

            let formatter = DateFormatter()
           formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            let dateSelected = formatter.string(from: self.selectedDate)

           let parameters = "{\n\t\"locale\": \”mainplace\”,\n\t\”date\": \"\(dateSelected)\",\n\t\"access_token\": \"\(token)\"\n}"
           let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

           var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://somelink:18999/salesAPI/localeSales")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
           request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

           request.httpMethod = "POST"
           request.httpBody = postData

           let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
               guard let data = data else {
                   print(String(describing: error))
                   return
               }
               print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)

               let decoder = JSONDecoder()

               if let jsonPetitions = try? decoder.decode(RootRequest.self, from: data) {
                   self.restaurants = jsonPetitions.results
                   showNumberOfRes = self.restaurants.count
                   print (" \(self.restaurants.count) got it from Json")

               }
               else {print("Nothing!!")}

        }

            task.resume()

          DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }

        }
    } // End Json

    func loadData() {
          tableView.reloadData()

        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
         userNameData = defaults.string(forKey: "userNameData")!
         passwordData = defaults.string(forKey: "passwordData")!
         token = defaults.string(forKey: "enterKey")!

        returnJson()

               }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         self.tableView.dataSource = self
         self.tableView.delegate = self

       returnJson()

    } // End of viewDidLoad

    // Starts Tables
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        print("\(showNumberOfRes) printed in the table")
        return showNumberOfRes

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell

            let displayNames = restaurants[indexPath.row]

             cell.locales.text = displayNames.locale

             return cell

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return CGFloat(80)

    }  // End Tables


}
```

Comment: By the way, unrelated to your question, there is no such locale as `es_ES_POSIX`. It’s `en_US_POSIX`. (I know, it feels jingoistic, but that’s just what used for ISO 8601 dates, and has nothing to do with your device language.) You’re not using this formatter and it should therefore be removed, so it really doesn’t matter, but just a FYI.

Comment: Thanks for that. I was curious about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reload the table view **inside** the completion handler of the data task.

Two other changes:

1. The background queue is redundant as `URLSession` spawns its own background queue
2. Never `try?` in a `JSONDecoder` line. Catch the `error` and print it

   ```
   func returnJson() {

      let formatter = DateFormatter()
      formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
      let dateSelected = formatter.string(from: self.selectedDate)

      let parameters = "{\n\t\"locale\": \”mainplace\”,\n\t\”date\": \"\(dateSelected)\",\n\t\"access_token\": \"\(token)\"\n}"
      let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

      var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://somelink:18999/salesAPI/localeSales")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
      request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

      request.httpMethod = "POST"
      request.httpBody = postData

      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
          guard let data = data else {
              print(error!)
              return
          }
          print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)

          let decoder = JSONDecoder()

          do {
              let jsonPetitions = try decoder.decode(RootRequest.self, from: data) 
              self.restaurants = jsonPetitions.results
              showNumberOfRes = self.restaurants.count
              print (" \(self.restaurants.count) got it from Json")
              DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  self.tableView.reloadData()
              }

          } catch {
              print(error)
          }
      }
      task.resume()

   } // End Json
   ```